# rubyの構文に関する質問

Tags: ruby

Ruby on Railsを使ってWebサイトを作っています。
Ruby,Rails共に初心者です。

capistrano3-unicorn gemの設定方法が分からず調べているのですが、
設定ファイルがサイトごとでいろいろな書き方がされており混乱しています。

### 質問１

https://github.com/tablexi/capistrano3-unicorn/blob/master/examples/unicorn.rb
上記URLにある `unicorn.rb` 2行目と3行目なのですが、

```
app_path = "/home/example/www.example.com"
working_directory "#{app_path}/current"
```

どちらも 変数宣言＋初期化 を行っているという認識であってますでしょうか？
`app_path` の行には `=` がありますが、`=` 有無で何が違うのでしょうか？
もしかして `working_directory` はgem内に定義されているsetter関数でしょうか？

### 質問２

http://jetglass.hatenablog.jp/entry/2015/07/06/143131
上記URLには下記記述があります。

```
def rails_root
  File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)
end
```

これは `rails_root` メソッドを定義し、`File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)` の結果を戻り値として返していますが、 `rails_root = File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)` とは書けないのでしょうか？
`File.expand_path`はメソッドなので、rails_rootというメソッドを定義して、その中で呼び出す必要があり、必然的にこのような書き方になっているのでしょうか？

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんが宜しくお願いいたします。
勘違いをしているようであればご指摘ください。

Comment: 関連ありゲ：http://www.rubydoc.info/github/defunkt/unicorn/Unicorn%2FConfigurator%3Aworking_directory このメソッドがCapistranoで定義されている前提でunicorn側から呼んでる？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問1については

```
app_path = "/home/example/www.example.com"
```

これは変数代入です。

```
working_directory "#{app_path}/current"
```

これは `=` がないので変数代入ではなくworking_directoryというメソッドの呼び出しではないかと思います。何の目的なのかは分かりません。

質問2については

```
def rails_root
  File.expand_path('../../', __FILE__)
end
```

これですが、これは恐らく読取専用アクセッサの役割を果たすためにこうなってると思います。
つまり、使う側からすると `Rails`のルートディレクトリを勝手に設定することはできないが、このメソッドを使うことであたかも代入するかのように

```
path = rails_root
```

と書けるようにしてあるのだと思います。
周辺コードの詳細を見てないのであくまでも一般論的な解釈ですが、いかがでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、woking_direcotry は、メソッド呼び出しです。configuration ですね。 https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/lib/unicorn/configurator.rb#L525-L543

Comment: ありがとうございます！
`working_directory`は別のところで定義してあるメソッドだったのですね。
`rails_root`についても意図が理解できスッキリしました。